# How can I raise ValidationError using DjangoForm?

Tags: python, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-validation

I am quite new to programming and I am trying to build my first webiste! 
I am trying to validate some fields of a form on server side and I cannot understand why it is not displayed to the user on HTML page. I have tried the different approaches, but unsuccessfully. I know it is quite newbie question, but I cannot understand why it is not working.

```
forms.py
class SuggestionForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=800, widget=forms.Textarea)


    def clean_text(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['text']
        print(data)
        if len(data) < 50:
            raise forms.ValidationError('The text cannot be smaller than 50 char')
        return data
```

views.py

```
def suggestion_add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SuggestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            suggestion = Suggestions.objects.create(
                name = form.cleaned_data['name'],
                last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            )
            suggestion.save()
            return redirect("success")
    else:
        form = SuggestionForm()
        form.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({
                    'placeholder': 'Your name'
                })
        form.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs.update({
                    'placeholder': 'Your surname'
                })
        form.fields['text'].widget.attrs.update({
                    'placeholder': 'Your thoughts'
                })

    return render(request, "suggestions_add.html", {'form':form})
```

html

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                <div id='id_name' class="control-group">
                    <label for="id_name" class="control-label">
                        Name
                    </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        {{ form.name }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id='id_prenume' class="control-group">
                    <label for="id_prenume" class="control-label">
                        Last name
                    </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        {{ form.last_name }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id='id_text' class="control-group">
                    <label for="id_text" class="control-label">
                        Text
                    </label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label for="field"></label>
                        {{ form.text }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="characters">
                        <span id="charNum"> </span> <span id="charText"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="wrap-send">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="drpbtn" id="send-sugestion">
                </div>
                {% csrf_token %}
            </form>
```

I tried every approach I found on internet, and definitely something's up with my code because I cannot understand why it is not showing the error to the user!

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Because you do not render any errors.

Comment: Well, when I use clean_fieldname() method, and I return the data collected from the page, the error isn't passed automatically to the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not render any errors. In order to render any errors, you should render not only the field but the errors as well. This is discussed in the [*rendering fields manually* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually). For example for your text field you can render the errors with:

```
{% if form.text.errors %}
    <ol>
    {% for error in form.text.errors %}
        <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endif %}
<div class="controls">
    <label for="field"></label>
    {{ form.text }}
</div>
```

You can of course add a different styling, etc.

You should do this for *all* form fields, since each field can raise errors.

Furthermore there can also be *non-field errors*: these are errors not related to a specific field, but often a combination of fields. These are typically rendered at the top of the form with something like:

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <ol>
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endif %}
```